# How could I interchange SpannableString to String without losing it's marked up properties?

Tags: android, spannablestring

If i have the following string:

```
String string = “My string”
```

Then i could change it’s color background using SpanString:

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(string);
BackgroundColorSpan backgroundSpan = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
spannableString.setSpan(backgroundSpan, 0, spannableString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Then if i make

`Toast(context , spannableString , Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();`

It will display a toast “My string” with changed background to red.

However , how can I show the same string without using the type SpannableString??
I mean Toast(context , [toString] spannableString , Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();

[toString]: my note

PS:I've tried

```
Toast.makeText(context, Html.fromHtml(spannableString.toString()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and

```
Toast.makeText(context, spannableString.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

because i need to attribute this to a kind of:

```
entity.setAttribute([toString]Spannable);
```

but not showing commom text.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way without using Spannables.  Spannables are how you add formatting data to text in Android.  Even your fromHTML hack turns html into a spannable.

The correct thing to do is probably take whatever API you're using that requires a string and make it take a CharSequence instead.

Comment: But i have an entity that needs to receive a text, but not specified with Spannable type.How can i accomplish this??

Comment: A String is a CharSequence. A Spannable is a CharSequence. Use CharSequence instead.

Comment: I've tried this, but i have sooo much code, and try to change every occurrence would be practically impossible...is there another way to do this?

Comment: Not very usage of String needs to be replaced-  just the ones in the path that holds formatted data

Comment: Firebase is bothering me com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class java.lang.CharSequence

Comment: I've tried all possibilites, but the problem is that i have something like
entity.setText([Spandable]). I've tried changing my entity constructor and attributes and etc